# Why negative number in the following if condition throws error?

Tags: haskell

I am watching 'Haskell Fundamentals Part 1' in Pluralsight. In the second chapter, the author shows an very simple function with **if** in it. When I tried it, I am getting error everytime when I tried the function with negative number. Here is the function

```
posOrNeg x = 
    if x >= 0
    then "Positive"
    else "Negative"
```

When I tried the method with positive number it worked fine but when I call the method with negative number, winGHCi throws following error.
"No instance for (Show (a0 -> [Char]))) arising from a use of 'print'..."
 Is it more to it then just the function here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way that you'd get a type error for applying a function to a negative number when applying the same function to a positive number of the same type works fine.

Without seeing the code, the most likely explanation is that you wrote something like `posOrNeg -42`, which is the same as `posOrNeg - 42` and tries to subtract 42 from `posOrNeg` (which isn't possible because, of course, you can't subtract a number from a function). The correct syntax to apply a function to a negative number is `posOrNeg (-42)` with parentheses around the number, so that's it's not possible to parse the `-` as an infix operator.

Comment: Yes I did not pass the negative number in parentheses. I did not know about that difference before. It make sense.

Comment: Note that with `-XNegativeLiterals`, you can do `posOrNeg -42` (but not `posOrNeg - 42`).

Comment: sometimes it's easier to use `negate` depends a bit on the situation